# Rails throws 'column must appear in the GROUP BY' exception for not apparent reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The situation is following:
SQL below yields correct results when run in `psql` or with          `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

```
SELECT SUM(loan_investments.amount) AS total_balance,
       COUNT(DISTINCT loan_investments.loan_id) AS number_of_loans,
       AVG(loan_investments.interest_rate) AS average_interest_rate,
       AVG(DATE_PART('month', loans.last_payment_date) - DATE_PART('month', NOW())) AS average_remaining_period 
FROM "loan_investments" 
INNER JOIN "loans" ON "loans"."id" = "loan_investments"."loan_id" 
WHERE "loan_investments"."user_id" = 8 
GROUP BY loan_investments.user_id;
```

Here is the scope that was used to generate the SQL above;

```
 scope :performance_overview, -> {
     investments = joins(:loan)
     investments = investments.select("SUM(loan_investments.amount) AS total_balance,
                                  COUNT(DISTINCT loan_investments.loan_id) AS number_of_loans,
                                  AVG(loan_investments.interest_rate) AS average_interest_rate,
                                  AVG(DATE_PART('month', loans.last_payment_date) - DATE_PART('month', NOW())) AS average_remaining_period")
     investments.group('loan_investments.user_id')
  }
```

When I run this scope the following exception is raised:

> ERROR:  column "loan_investments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Which is totally unexpected because loan_investments.id is not even used anywhere, and when this sql is run in console it yields correct result. My guess here is that ActiveRecord wants to group by `loan_investments.id` because we query model `LoanInvestment`, but I don't know if this is correct.

So the question is why this exception is raised?

Comment: Have you looked in the debug log what SQL statement is actually generated? That error (likely) doesn't come from Rails, but from Postgres, which means the generated SQL is not what you think it is.

Comment: You might want to check the SQL that is generated by this scope by adding [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) to the end.

Comment: The provided sql is what I receive from running .to_sql on given scope

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an assignment at the last line ...

```
scope :performance_overview, -> {
 investments = joins(:loan)
 investments = investments.select("SUM(loan_investments.amount) AS total_balance,
                              COUNT(DISTINCT loan_investments.loan_id) AS number_of_loans,
                              AVG(loan_investments.interest_rate) AS average_interest_rate,
                              AVG(DATE_PART('month', loans.last_payment_date) - DATE_PART('month', NOW())) AS average_remaining_period")
 investments = investments.group('loan_investments.user_id')
```

}

Comment: Im not quite sure why do I need an additional assignment on the last line, because investments.group('loan_investments.user_id') returns scoped relation as it should

Comment: because it's always an addition to `invenstments`. but if the model IS `Invenstment` and the scope is inside, you just join the elements with "." together - without any assignments.